# Calculate the specified value between two dates using case php

Tags: countif

table employee

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | name1 |
| 2 | name2 |
| 3 | Name3 |

Table att

| emp_id | attstatus | attdate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | absent | 02-02-2023 |
| 1 | absent | 01-03-2023 |
| 1 | Absent | 05-03-2023 |

I want a php query

How do I get the employee table data?

And calculate the number of days of absence for each employee between two dates

And zero for an employee who has no absence